# Xamarin iOS Storyboard having rendering error NullReferenceException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

When opening storyboard recently, the ViewController in the Storyboard will have problem rendering. It is showing NullReferenceException.
[image]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that we need to disable the rendering of screen in UI Designer (Recent version of Xamarin will add the screen into Custom Components too).

To turn off the rendering, we need to set the DesignTimeVisible flag to false.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisible(false)]
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
```

I have also written more details in my blog [HERE](https://lowleetak.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/xamarin-ios-storyboard-rendering-problem-with-nullreferenceexception/).